# why is printf causing my program to crash

Tags: java

Hello I am a beginner and I am trying to print a value to 1 decimal place using printf in java; however I am getting an error at the time of conversion. Here is the line of the error.

```java
System.out.printf( " us Ratio = %.1f us/compare \n " , elapsedTime/1000 );
```

Comment: what is `elapsedTime`? is it a float, integer, String? are you certain it isn't `null` either? Can you paste the exception stacktrace and some code before this call to demonstrate what is going on?

Comment: Have you at least read the error message? Don't you think it might contain useful information, helping to diagnose the problem? If so, why don't you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code with this :

```
System.out.printf(" us Ratio = %.1f us/compare \n ", (float)(elapsedTime / 1000));
```

You were getting error because you were not providing `float` as argument where required.
You must use an expression which will implicitly cast to `float` or cast it explicitly as shown above.

**can use `double` as well here**

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on tick when you found any answer useful or best when there are more then 1 useful answers. This way the answerer will gain 15 reputations and you will gain 2.

Answer (score 1):

Define `elapsedTime` as a float

Ex. `elapsedTime = 1f;`

Then it will work. Or you can also cast the result of `(elapsedTime/ 1000)` to `float`

Something like - `((float) (elapsedTime/ 1000))`

Comment: a hipfire guess? he could also just cast to float if that is the case.